# Clover does not detect any tests at all

Tags: java, testing, surefire, clover

I'm using Clover in a project, to help get test coverage over 7%.
I separated and renamed unit tests and integration tests into *Test.java and *IT.java, and added Surefire to reduce build times.
All tests run fine.

Now suddenly Clover says test coverage is 0%.

What can be the reason for this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working again by removing Clover and Surefire, and then adding Clover with only simple settings